# Your connection is not private github.com NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID + DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA certificate is valid

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I know this has been discussed elsewhere but none of the solutions worked...

When accessing github.com since yesterday I got

> Your connection is not private github.com NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID

When checking for more info it says the Certificate is invalid:

[image]

But when clicking for more details it says my certificate **is valid**:

[image]

Now, I've tried to follow instructions [here](https://www.digicert.com/blog/expired-intermediate-certificate/) as suggested in other posts, but I can't delete the certificate (which actually looks valid):

[image]

More info:

- my user is Admin
- I'm on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
- date/time is ok
- Chrome Version 67.0.3396.62
- Also doesn't work on Canary Version 69.0.3451.0
- Does work on Firefox Version 60.0.1
- Does work on Safari Version 11.0.3
- Does work with curl
- I have changed the "Trust" settings of the DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA certificate in my System Root to "Always trust" (they were "Use System Defaults" before)
- I have downloaded a new certificate from https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm, copied to my "login" keychain items and set to "Always trust"

Still not working...

UPDATE for @grawity

- This is what I see under "Advanced"

  > github.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When
  >   Google Chrome tried to connect to github.com this time, the website
  >   sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an
  >   attacker is trying to pretend to be github.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in
  >   screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still
  >   secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data
  >   was exchanged.
  >
  > You cannot visit github.com right now because the website sent
  >   scrambled credentials that Google Chrome cannot process. Network
  >   errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably
  >   work later.
- This is what I see after clicking on the error

  > NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID Subject: github.com
  >
  > Issuer: DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
  >
  > Expires on: Jun 3, 2020
  >
  > Current date: Jun 6, 2018
  >
  > PEM encoded chain:
  >   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIHQjCCBiqgAwIBAgIQCgYwQn9bvO1pVzllk7ZFHzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB1
  >   MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
  >   d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMTQwMgYDVQQDEytEaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEV4dGVuZGVk
  >   IFZhbGlkYXRpb24gU2VydmVyIENBMB4XDTE4MDUwODAwMDAwMFoXDTIwMDYwMzEy
  >   MDAwMFowgccxHTAbBgNVBA8MFFByaXZhdGUgT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uMRMwEQYLKwYB
  >   BAGCNzwCAQMTAlVTMRkwFwYLKwYBBAGCNzwCAQITCERlbGF3YXJlMRAwDgYDVQQF
  >   Ewc1MTU3NTUwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQG
  >   A1UEBxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEVMBMGA1UEChMMR2l0SHViLCBJbmMuMRMwEQYD
  >   VQQDEwpnaXRodWIuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA
  >   xjyq8jyXDDrBTyitcnB90865tWBzpHSbindG/XqYQkzFMBlXmqkzC+FdTRBYyneZ
  >   w5Pz+XWQvL+74JW6LsWNc2EF0xCEqLOJuC9zjPAqbr7uroNLghGxYf13YdqbG5oj
  >   /4x+ogEG3dF/U5YIwVr658DKyESMV6eoYV9mDVfTuJastkqcwero+5ZAKfYVMLUE
  >   sMwFtoTDJFmVf6JlkOWwsxp1WcQ/MRQK1cyqOoUFUgYylgdh3yeCDPeF22Ax8AlQ
  >   xbcaI+GwfQL1FB7Jy+h+KjME9lE/UpgV6Qt2R1xNSmvFCBWu+NFX6epwFP/JRbkM
  >   fLz0beYFUvmMgLtwVpEPSwIDAQABo4IDeTCCA3UwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUPdNQpdag
  >   re7zSmAKZdMh1Pj41g8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFMnCU2FmnV+rJfQmzQ84mqhJ6kipMCUG
  >   A1UdEQQeMByCCmdpdGh1Yi5jb22CDnd3dy5naXRodWIuY29tMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQE
  >   AwIFoDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwdQYDVR0fBG4wbDA0
  >   oDKgMIYuaHR0cDovL2NybDMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL3NoYTItZXYtc2VydmVyLWcy
  >   LmNybDA0oDKgMIYuaHR0cDovL2NybDQuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL3NoYTItZXYtc2Vy
  >   dmVyLWcyLmNybDBLBgNVHSAERDBCMDcGCWCGSAGG/WwCATAqMCgGCCsGAQUFBwIB
  >   FhxodHRwczovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BTMAcGBWeBDAEBMIGIBggrBgEF
  >   BQcBAQR8MHowJAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTBS
  >   BggrBgEFBQcwAoZGaHR0cDovL2NhY2VydHMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0RpZ2lDZXJ0
  >   U0hBMkV4dGVuZGVkVmFsaWRhdGlvblNlcnZlckNBLmNydDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAA
  >   MIIBfgYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSCAW4EggFqAWgAdgCkuQmQtBhYFIe7E6LMZ3AKPDWY
  >   BPkb37jjd80OyA3cEAAAAWNBYm0KAAAEAwBHMEUCIQDRZp38cTWsWH2GdBpe/uPT
  >   Wnsu/m4BEC2+dIcvSykZYgIgCP5gGv6yzaazxBK2NwGdmmyuEFNSg2pARbMJlUFg
  >   U5UAdgBWFAaaL9fC7NP14b1Esj7HRna5vJkRXMDvlJhV1onQ3QAAAWNBYm0tAAAE
  >   AwBHMEUCIQCi7omUvYLm0b2LobtEeRAYnlIo7n6JxbYdrtYdmPUWJQIgVgw1AZ51
  >   vK9ENinBg22FPxb82TvNDO05T17hxXRC2IYAdgC72d+8H4pxtZOUI5eqkntHOFeV
  >   CqtS6BqQlmQ2jh7RhQAAAWNBYm3fAAAEAwBHMEUCIQChzdTKUU2N+XcqcK0OJYrN
  >   8EYynloVxho4yPk6Dq3EPgIgdNH5u8rC3UcslQV4B9o0a0w204omDREGKTVuEpxG
  >   eOQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAHAPWpanWOW/ip2oJ5grAH8mqQfaunuCVE+v
  >   ac+88lkDK/LVdFgl2B6kIHZiYClzKtfczG93hWvKbST4NRNHP9LiaQqdNC17e5vN
  >   HnXVUGw+yxyjMLGqkgepOnZ2Rb14kcTOGp4i5AuJuuaMwXmCo7jUwPwfLe1NUlVB
  >   Kqg6LK0Hcq4K0sZnxE8HFxiZ92WpV2AVWjRMEc/2z2shNoDvxvFUYyY1Oe67xINk
  >   myQKc+ygSBZzyLnXSFVWmHr3u5dcaaQGGAR42v6Ydr4iL38Hd4dOiBma+FXsXBIq
  >   WUjbST4VXmdaol7uzFMojA4zkxQDZAvF5XgJlAFadfySna/teik=
  >   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  >   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIEtjCCA56gAwIBAgIQDHmpRLCMEZUgkmFf4msdgzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBs
  >   MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
  >   d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSswKQYDVQQDEyJEaWdpQ2VydCBIaWdoIEFzc3VyYW5j
  >   ZSBFViBSb290IENBMB4XDTEzMTAyMjEyMDAwMFoXDTI4MTAyMjEyMDAwMFowdTEL
  >   MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEZMBcGA1UECxMQd3d3
  >   LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTE0MDIGA1UEAxMrRGlnaUNlcnQgU0hBMiBFeHRlbmRlZCBW
  >   YWxpZGF0aW9uIFNlcnZlciBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoC
  >   ggEBANdTpARR+JmmFkhLZyeqk0nQOe0MsLAAh/FnKIaFjI5j2ryxQDji0/XspQUY
  >   uD0+xZkXMuwYjPrxDKZkIYXLBxA0sFKIKx9om9KxjxKws9LniB8f7zh3VFNfgHk/
  >   LhqqqB5LKw2rt2O5Nbd9FLxZS99RStKh4gzikIKHaq7q12TWmFXo/a8aUGxUvBHy
  >   /Urynbt/DvTVvo4WiRJV2MBxNO723C3sxIclho3YIeSwTQyJ3DkmF93215SF2AQh
  >   cJ1vb/9cuhnhRctWVyh+HA1BV6q3uCe7seT6Ku8hI3UarS2bhjWMnHe1c63YlC3k
  >   8wyd7sFOYn4XwHGeLN7x+RAoGTMCAwEAAaOCAUkwggFFMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYB
  >   Af8CAQAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEF
  >   BQcDAjA0BggrBgEFBQcBAQQoMCYwJAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmRp
  >   Z2ljZXJ0LmNvbTBLBgNVHR8ERDBCMECgPqA8hjpodHRwOi8vY3JsNC5kaWdpY2Vy
  >   dC5jb20vRGlnaUNlcnRIaWdoQXNzdXJhbmNlRVZSb290Q0EuY3JsMD0GA1UdIAQ2
  >   MDQwMgYEVR0gADAqMCgGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhxodHRwczovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5j
  >   b20vQ1BTMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQ901Cl1qCt7vNKYApl0yHU+PjWDzAfBgNVHSMEGDAW
  >   gBSxPsNpA/i/RwHUmCYaCALvY2QrwzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAnbbQkIbh
  >   hgLtxaDwNBx0wY12zIYKqPBKikLWP8ipTa18CK3mtlC4ohpNiAexKSHc59rGPCHg
  >   4xFJcKx6HQGkyhE6V6t9VypAdP3THYUYUN9XR3WhfVUgLkc3UHKMf4Ib0mKPLQNa
  >   2sPIoc4sUqIAY+tzunHISScjl2SFnjgOrWNoPLpSgVh5oywM395t6zHyuqB8bPEs
  >   1OG9d4Q3A84ytciagRpKkk47RpqF/oOi+Z6Mo8wNXrM9zwR4jxQUezKcxwCmXMS1
  >   oVWNWlZopCJwqjyBcdmdqEU79OX2olHdx3ti6G8MdOu42vi/hw15UJGQmxg7kVkn
  >   8TUoE6smftX3eg==
  >   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  >   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDxTCCAq2gAwIBAgIQAqxcJmoLQJuPC3nyrkYldzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBs
  >   MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
  >   d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSswKQYDVQQDEyJEaWdpQ2VydCBIaWdoIEFzc3VyYW5j
  >   ZSBFViBSb290IENBMB4XDTA2MTExMDAwMDAwMFoXDTMxMTExMDAwMDAwMFowbDEL
  >   MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEZMBcGA1UECxMQd3d3
  >   LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTErMCkGA1UEAxMiRGlnaUNlcnQgSGlnaCBBc3N1cmFuY2Ug
  >   RVYgUm9vdCBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMbM5XPm
  >   +9S75S0tMqbf5YE/yc0lSbZxKsPVlDRnogocsF9ppkCxxLeyj9CYpKlBWTrT3JTW PNt0OKRKzE0lgvdKpVMSOO7zSW1xkX5jtqumX8OkhPhPYlG++MXs2ziS4wblCJEM
  >   xChBVfvLWokVfnHoNb9Ncgk9vjo4UFt3MRuNs8ckRZqnrG0AFFoEt7oT61EKmEFB
  >   Ik5lYYeBQVCmeVyJ3hlKV9Uu5l0cUyx+mM0aBhakaHPQNAQTXKFx01p8VdteZOE3
  >   hzBWBOURtCmAEvF5OYiiAhF8J2a3iLd48soKqDirCmTCv2ZdlYTBoSUeh10aUAsg
  >   EsxBu24LUTi4S8sCAwEAAaNjMGEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQF
  >   MAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFLE+w2kD+L9HAdSYJhoIAu9jZCvDMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaA
  >   FLE+w2kD+L9HAdSYJhoIAu9jZCvDMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQAcGgaX3Nec
  >   nzyIZgYIVyHbIUf4KmeqvxgydkAQV8GK83rZEWWONfqe/EW1ntlMMUu4kehDLI6z
  >   eM7b41N5cdblIZQB2lWHmiRk9opmzN6cN82oNLFpmyPInngiK3BD41VHMWEZ71jF
  >   hS9OMPagMRYjyOfiZRYzy78aG6A9+MpeizGLYAiJLQwGXFK3xPkKmNEVX58Svnw2
  >   Yzi9RKR/5CYrCsSXaQ3pjOLAEFe4yHYSkVXySGnYvCoCWw9E1CAx2/S6cCZdkGCe
  >   vEsXCS+0yx5DaMkHJ8HSXPfqIbloEpw8nL+e/IBcm2PN7EeqJSdnoDfzAIJ9VNep
  >   +OkuE6N36B9K
  >   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: What do you see in the error page after expanding the "Advanced" section? Also, what do you see in the error page after clicking on "NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID" and expanding the hidden technical details section?

Comment: @grawity added error messages

Comment: @Run5k thx for the heads up, solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this is how I solved the issue on my machine after a few hours of reading here and there and trial and error:

1. Download the *DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA* certificate from http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2ExtendedValidationServerCA.crt
2. Double-click on the downloaded file and it will be added to the login certificates list in Keychain
3. Double-click on the certificate in the Keychain login list
4. Show the "Trust" options
5. Select the "Always Trust" option of the "When using this certificate:" field
6. Close and save
7. Refresh the error page (github.com in my case)

Since the URI to download the certificate might change over time, this is how I have found it:

1. click on the crossed red lock in the address bar of the error page
2. click on the certificate (invalid) item of the dialog
3. the new dialog will have the problematic certificate pre-selected (it said it was valid in my case...)
4. scroll down to find a series of URI fields and click on the one ending with .crt

Cheers